# What is the meaning of the operator += in sql

Tags: sql

While coding I came across the following line of code.  WHat does this operator means?!!

```
String sql = "SELECT INTL_SERVICE_CENTER_CODE AS ISC_CODE, ";
sql += "COUNT(SHIPDATA_IMAGE_KEY) AS TPARCELS_FILTERED, ";
```

Comment: Which database server is this?

Comment: This is not a SQL operator... you must be using another language. It normally means re-create the variable on the left hand side as the value of that variable plus the value of the right hand side.

Comment: @Ben: in SQL Server 2008+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645922(v=sql.100).aspx This is not SQL Server dialect though, indeed is it SQL at all?

Comment: I don't think that's SQL. It could be the Java library/drivers/abstraction (for example). `rset` is the result of some earlier query, and `getInt` returns the returned-value in the query with the column `CGT25`
The `+=` is just regular whatever-language-that-is "increment"

Comment: In java (or other C-based languages) `c25Ctr += rset.getInt("CGT25");` is equivalent to `c25Ctr = c25Ctr + rset.getInt("CGT25");`. Likewise, there are operators for `-=, /= and *=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle SQL, "+" is an [outer join operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm). But what you posted isn't Oracle SQL. As far as I know, the "+" join operator isn't deprecated, but DBAs usually regard its use as a mistake, except in maintaining legacy code. (Use ANSI join syntax instead.)

In procedural languages, a statement in the form `a += b` usually means `a = a + b`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Exactly what i was looking for Im not sure why Im being punished by these Down Votes!!

Answer (score 1):

Most of those operator symbols have the same meening in the most programming languages...There is no definition in SQL for this operator, so we could just explain this as an addition.. 
So basically this operator is just a shortcut to write this one :

```
 c25Ctr = c25Ctr + rset.getInt("CGT25");
 cilCtr = cilCtr + rset.getInt("CIL");
```

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is a standard "Compound Assignment" operator in several languages

- [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645922%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [Java](http://java.about.com/od/c/g/compoundassgnment.htm)

In this case, it isn't SQL but

> append and assign the integer conversion of a field in a recordset